# Using a formtype to edit object

Tags: symfony

I am trying to use a formtype to edit one of my objects.
The formtype is working flawlessly when creating new objects, but when I try to load an existing entity into the form, I get the following exception:

Entity of type "Proxies__CG__\App\Entity\Language" passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe you forget to persist it in the entity manager?

The object which gets put into the form is loaded from the database, so it is 100% persisted already.

Here are the types:

UnitType

```
class UnitType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('unitTranslations', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => UnitTranslationType::class,
                'entry_options' => array('label' => false),
                'allow_add'    => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'prototype'    => true,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'delete_empty' => true,
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'UnitTranslationSelector',
                ],
            ])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Unit::class
        ));
    }
}
```

UnitTranslationType

```
class UnitTranslationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder
            ->add('name', TextType::class, [
                'label' => 'Unit',
                'by_reference' => false
            ])
            ->add('language', EntityType::class, [
                'class' => Language::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
                'placeholder' => 'Choose an option',
                'by_reference' => false
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => UnitTranslation::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

and the controller:

```
public function createUnit(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
    {
        $unit = new Unit();

        $unit = $entityManager->getRepository(Unit::class)->find(2);
        dump($unit);

        $form = $this->createForm(UnitType::class, $unit);

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

            foreach ($unit->getUnitTranslations() as $translation) {
                $translation->setUnit($unit);
            }

            $entityManager->persist($unit);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute("recipe_list");
        }
        return $this->render('createUnit.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));

    }
```

Comment: This is just a pure guess but is the property Unit::unitTranslations public by any chance?

Comment: @Cerad nope, the property is private

Comment: Too bad.  So why is there a by_reference attribute in your language EntityType?

Comment: to be honest, I don't know why this attribute was there, but the by_reference is the problem, when I remove it so it's default set to true the loading works without any problems

Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it is working.  Always enjoy solutions when neither the helper nor the helpee understand why it works.

Comment: yeah it is really weird, but as long as it is working I'm happy :) do you want to make an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: Nah.  Maybe somebody else will come by and provide an actual explanation.

Comment: I think problem was with Unit::addUnitTranslation() method.. As `'by_reference' => false,` will result to call this function

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I just solved this same problem by using CollectionType instead of EntityType (for the language entity in your case). I'm not sure how your entities are set up, but the CollectionType would require a OneToMany or ManyToMany relationship between UnitTranslation entity and Language entity. Description for CollectionType can be found [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) and how to embed a collection of forms can be found [there](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html).